# NodeJS - RegEx that will get me sentences with email addresses in them?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, cheerio

I'm requesting a URL's HTML, and loading the HTML into the [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) module with this code.

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request(url, function(err, http, body) {
  if(err) throw err;
  else {
    
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
        desc = $('.desc');
    
    // checkpoint
  }
});
```

At the checkpoint, I need to find sentences that contain email addresses. I tried this code in place of `//checkpoint` with no luck.

```js
var regex = /\n|([^\r\n.!?]+([.!?]+|$))/gim,
    str = $(desc).text(),
    sentences = str.match(regex)[0];

    console.log(str);
    // 'Hello! My email is jerry@gmail.com.'

    console.log(sentences);
    // ['Hello!', 'My email is jerry@gmail.', 'com.']
```

I started to understand the RegEx, and tried the code below in place of `//checkpoint`.

```js
var regex = /\n|([^\r\n.!?]+([.!?]+|$))/gim,
    regex_email = require('xemplar').information.email,
    str = $(desc).text(),
    email = str.match(regex_email)[0];

    console.log(email);
    // jerry@gmail.com

var needle = email.replace('.', '[[dot]]');
    str = str.replace(email, needle),
    sentences = str.match(regex)[0],
    len = sentences.length;

    console.log(str);
    // 'Hello! My email is jerry@gmail[[dot]]com.'

    console.log(sentences);
    // ['Hello!', 'My email is jerry@gmail[[dot]]com.']


while(len--) {
    if(sentences[len].indexOf(needle) > -1) {
        console.log(sentences[len];
        // 'My email is jerry@gmail[[dot]]com.'
    }
}
```

But, here's the problem; **I want to preserve the HTML.**

Is there a way to do something like this in place of `//checkpoint`?

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    regex = require('xemplar').information.email;

request(url, function(err, http, body) {
  if(err) throw err;
  else {
    
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
        desc = $('.desc');
    
    // how do I get all bottom level tags?
    var bottomleveltags = $(desc).someFunction();
        bottomleveltags.forEach(function(tag) {
          
          var email = tag.match(regex)[0],
              tagbody = $(tag).text();
          
          var needle = email.replace('.', '[[dot]]');
              tagbody = tagbody.replace(email, needle);
          
          var sentences = tagbody.match(/\n|([^\r\n.!?]+([.!?]+|$))/gim);
          
          sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {
            if(sentence.indexOf(needle) > -1) {
                
              console.log(sentence);
              // 'My email is jerry@gmail[[dot]]com'
            }
          });
        });
  }
});
```

Is there a more obvious way to do this than with [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)? If there's not, how would I select all of the bottom level elements' sentences without calling `$.text()` on the whole thing?

Comment: get more specific: "sentences" have no HTML in them. For instance, if what you really need is HTML paragraphs with email addresses in their textContent, why not search for that? Get the list of all `<p>` elements and then filter based on whether their textContent matches the email regex (which you are not going to write yourself, [it's insane](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), use a premade matcher), discarding anything that doesn't match. What's left is the set of elements that match your criterium.